# broom::tidy or glance with rms::lrm now results in error

Tags: r, rms, broom

I was previously able to use broom::tidy and broom::glance on rms::lrm objects. However, trying to do so now results in errors.

Previously, broom::tidy on a rms:lrm object would provide the following (values are made up):

```
term    estimate    std.error   statistic   p.value
y>=six      -2.1         0.76       -2.78      0.01
y>=eight   -4.98         1.16       -4.31         0
mpg         0.08         0.02        3.97         0
```

and broom::glance would output values for the following:

```
obs max.deriv   model.lr    df  p.value concordance somers.d    gamma   tau.a   r.squared   brier   g   gr  gp
```

But now I get errors. I tried installing previous versions of both broom and rms, but this has not resolved the errors. I am currently using `R 3.4.2`

```
library(dplyr)
library(rms)
library(broom)
data("mtcars")

df <- mtcars %>% select(mpg, cyl)
df$CYL <- factor(df$cyl, levels = c(6,4,8), labels=c("six", "four", "eight")) #ordered factor for ordinal logistic

fit <- lrm(CYL~mpg, data=df)
tidy(fit)
```

broom::tidy error

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(x) : 
  cannot coerce class "c("lrm", "rms", "glm")" to a data.frame
In addition: Warning message:
In tidy.default(fit) :
  No method for tidying an S3 object of class lrm , using as.data.frameNo method for tidying an S3 object of class rms , using as.data.frameNo method for tidying an S3 object of class glm , using as.data.frame
```

broom::glance error

```
Error in summary.rms(x) : 
  adjustment values not defined here or with datadist for mpg
```

Comment: `lrm` is not in the methods for 'tidy' `grep("lrm", methods("tidy"))#
integer(0)`  Could you provide the version which worked?

Comment: I know that it seems like this shouldn't work. But I have my old code and output and it did work. Unfortunately, I am not sure what version of the packages I was using. I last used broom::tidy with rms::lrm in May 2017, but was for sure using an 3.2 version of R then.

Comment: Possibly there could be changes in broom or rlm that created the bug